# Unity3D crash when running DLLimports in x86 architectures

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, 32bit-64bit, dllimport

I have been working on a unity wrapper that will enable some DLLs written in C/C++. The wrapper and the DLL work perfectly on 64 bit architectures but when tried to compile for 32 bit architecture it fails. The C# wrapper looks like this:

```
public class somePlugin : IDisposable
{
public IntPtr __this  = IntPtr.Zero;

public somePlugin()
{
    __this = CreateTheOject();
}

public bool initialize(ref uint area, ref uint volume)
{
    return CPP_init(__this, ref area, ref volume);
}

//C imports
[DllImport("interface100")]
private static extern IntPtr CreateTheObject();

//C++ imports

[DllImport("interface100", EntryPoint = "?init@Interface@@QAE_NPEA0@Z", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
private static extern bool CPP_init(IntPtr _this, ref uint area, ref uint volume);

};
```

The C function CreateTheOject() returns without problem. But when the C++ function CPP_init is called, Unity crashes completely. The crash comes from the DLL itself. its header looks like this:

```
bool objectInterface::init(unsigned int* area, unsigned int* volume);
```

Debugging the problem I found out that the actual value of area is received by the DLL in place of the volume. The value of volume is lost and Unity crashes perhaps due to a segmentation fault.

Does anyone have any ideas on what the problem might be?

Comment: Is there two versions of the dll.  One compiled in 64 and the other compiled in 32.  A 64 bit dll will not work in a 32 bit environment.

Comment: Yes. I have both versions. x64 and x86 with the source code being exactly the same. I import x64 when I compile in x64 and x86 when I compile x86. Importing x64 is no problem. but when I import x86 the project crashes.

Comment: Are you sure you are actual rebuilding everything?  The compiler dependencies may not recognize the the switching of the dll's because the dates of the files.  I usually delete either or both the obj/bin folder in project to force a complete rebuild.

Comment: @Alex Where did you put those two files in your Android project?

Comment: Ill try recompiling @jdweng. However the tool "depends" shows that it is in fact a 32 bit DLL.

Comment: It is a Unity3D project but it is not aimed for Android at the moment. I just have the DLL in my assets folder